# Azure - Outgoing SSH connection - timeout

Tags: centos, ssh, azure

I have problem with **ssh** **outgoing** connection with Azure - Centos 7 image - public IP.

Simply timeout. I see on all settings, and I think that all is fine. Any ideas?

**azure newbie**

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean outgoing SSH connection? Are you saying you can't connect to VM in Azure using public IP?

Answer (score 0):

You can check these steps:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/detailed-troubleshoot-ssh-connection

But basically you need to setup a security rule and allow incoming and outgoing traffic for port 22 to all IP addresses (or your VPN IP if applicable).